# Is there a way I can try a file upload (image) without actually writing the server side code?

Tags: android

I haven't wrote any server side code till now. Is there any way I can try writing an android program where I can write the file being uploaded from the mobile to a remote server?

Additional details:-
My code -

```
private void sendToRemoteServer(){
         Socket client;
         FileInputStream fileInputStream;
         BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream;
         OutputStream outputStream;

         try{
             client                 =   new Socket("10.0.2.2",444);
             byte[] myByteArray     =   new byte[(int)mFile.length()];
             fileInputStream        =   new FileInputStream(mFile);
             bufferedInputStream    =   new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);

             bufferedInputStream.read(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.length); //read the file

             outputStream = client.getOutputStream();

             outputStream.write(myByteArray, 0, myByteArray.length); //write file to the output stream byte by byte
             outputStream.flush();
             bufferedInputStream.close();
             outputStream.close();
             client.close();
         }catch(UnknownHostException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
            }
    }
```

All I need to make sure is that android doesn't run out of memory exception.

Comment: ...I'm highly doubtful of this (a connection requires 2 parties) my only advice would be to look to see if a site like flickr has an api you could tap into to do this ... unless someone else on S.O has a hack to do so

Comment: How to incorporate an api into the above code? Any clue on that?

Answer (score 2):

There are several options. One is to use webDAV or FTP on server. But nowadays there is a lot of file storage services which you can access with RESTful API like Amazon S3

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to [mock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object) a Server. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393099/mocking-http-server is a good point to start from.

Comment: I am a newbie in the programming world,It could be of great help if you provide me with some more details. I have edited the question by inclusion of some code. All I need to ensure is that android doesn't give an out of memory error. Is there any ready made website and port number that accepts the file?

Comment: if it is just about memory issues, you could direct your stream into a file on the sd-card.